# insert Ajax result in input field

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$('body').on("click", '.saveimage', function () {     
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "save.php",
        data: foo.crop(570, 765, 'png')
    }).done(function(data) {                
       $('#ajaxDiv').html(data);
    });
});
```

When I get the result from save.php i need to insert it in other form in hidden input field

For example:

```
<div class="ajaxDiv">
    <form method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="result from ajax">
        <input type="submit" value="ok">
    </form>
</div
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly you should give the hidden input an id so you can select it:

```
<input type="hidden" value="" id="result">
```

Then you can use the `val()` method to set its value to the AJAX response:

```
.done(function(data) {
   $('#result').val(data);
});
```

Comment: Many thanks! it works! Can you help me with other question? Is it possible to hide submit button before ajax will return #result value?

Comment: Yes, hide the submit button in CSS using `display: none`, and then in the `done()` handler add a call to `.show()` on the element.